# Oracle Search Function in Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQLDeveloper table   with a column which indicates a date.

On the top of the table there is a filter function and i would like to know how to search for a specific date. For example: What do i write as SQL command in the filter to find the date "`20141119`" (the format is "`yyyymmdd`")

Comment: what is the type of that column ?

Comment: the type of data in that column is VARCHAR2

Comment: what i am trying to do is just use the filter function to display all results with date "20141119"

Comment: @paul You should **not** store dates in Oracle as varchar2. You should use datetime. This clears up ambiguity on what format the date is in and allows you to directly filter on the date without the need for extra function calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, you can use `to_char()` to convert the values.  You need to be careful because an Oracle `date` column can also contain a time component:

```
WHERE trunc(col) = to_date('201411119', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

However, it is best to avoid having a function call on the column name -- this impedes the use of indexes.  So, if you *know* there is no time component, then use:

```
WHERE col = to_date('201411119', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

If you are not 100% sure, then use:

```
WHERE col >= to_date('201411119', 'YYYYMMDD') AND col < to_date('201411119', 'YYYYMMDD') + 1
```

EDIT:

If the type is `varchar2()`, then presumably it is in the same format as the input.  You can do:

```
WHERE SUBSTR(SENDINGTIME, 1, 8) = '20141119'
```

If it has another format, then you should use `to_date()` to convert it as described above.

In general, you should store dates and times using native database formats -- after all, that is why they are there.  If you do have to store them as a character, then YYYYMMDD is a good choice of format.

Comment: i tried all of your commands in the filter but neither gave me the desired output regarding the "20141119". I should add that the column with the dates is labeled "SENDINGTIME"